# Where are instructions for latest Ubuntu Studio Set Up Utility (2.3.1)

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I recently installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04. When I run the Studio Controls app, it doesn't match the instructions on the [ubuntu help website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioControls) which says "This section is for the version of Ubuntu Studio Controls 1.12.6 included with Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS". I have Ubuntu Studio Controls 2.3.1. It has different field names, more tabs, and some drop-down values don't match, so I thoroughly confused - I never used the older version and have no point of reference.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/ovenwerks/studio-controls/wiki

Comment: that's yet another version :) though much closer to the new one, and it did help. Thanks!